# auto answer to a sh echo

Tags: shell, echo, rsync

I use rsync in a script to make backup directly on a vmware server.

I try to find how to anwser by $BackupPassword when the script echo $BackupUser@$BackupIP\'s password:

I try few redirection before and after the line, use the option --password-file but **rsync not is not in daemon** version, ... so i'm stuck.

```
 **     START THE LINE     **
```

./rsync -avzrt '-e ssh' /vmfs/volumes/${VMpath%/*}/* $BackupUser@$BackupIP:$BackupStorage --exclude *000001* --exclude *Snapshot*

```
 **    END THE LINE     **
```

VMware user SH not BASH, it base on RedHat/CentOS, and accept statically compiled command.
So i can't use EXCEPT, except if you show me how to compile EXCEPT statically on CentOS 3.9 x86

Comment: You need to use ssh keys. Read up on `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: so simple; in ESXi 5.x, the ssh-keygen command is located at /usr/lib/vmware/openssh/bin. everything works by itself now ;)